# How to perform queuing and caching using redis for a multi-tenant multi-database architecture application in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5, queue

I am working on a multi-tenant multi-database architecture application using Laravel which basically means that every tenant in the application has their own database, own sets of users, resources and so on.

Now I am trying to implement queues and caching in the application, then I am trying to use redis for that. A sample code looks like this:

```
$mailer->send('emails.welcome', ['user' => $user], function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->from("admin@admin.com", "Admin");
    $message->to($user->email, $user->first_name)->subject("Welcome!");
});
```

This is to send a welcome email to user sign-up. But the queuing is storing all the queues in the same database in the same Redis instance, different tenant emails will get mixed up as far as I can tell.

How do I hook into Laravel 5 and change the queue behavior to either store the jobs for each tenant in a separate database or store extra meta-information about the tenant a particular job belongs to? And then also how would I tell Laravel to parse that extra meta-information and connect to the right tenant database before proceeding with the job?

Answer (score 1):

For appropriate work of Queue system, you need to use your own implementation of `\Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` trait inside your Jobs. Wheech will save and init correct DB connection on `Job::__sleep()` and `Job::__wakeup()`. 
Take a look at [TenantAwareJob trait](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/blob/5.x/src/Queue/TenantAwareJob.php) of [hyn/multi-tenant](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.x/queues) package.

For appropriate work of Cache system, you need to use a prefix which depends on the current host. Take a look how [hyn/multi-tenant](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.x/cache) developers recommend to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem generally as the queue is simply a queue. i.e. the tasks in it contain the real needed data, if you want to 'categorize' the queues for better management, you may the `onQueue` method to specify the queue or `onConnection` to [specify the connection you want to dispatch to](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection).

e.g.

```
EmailJob::dispatch($podcast)
    ->onConnection('sqs')
    ->onQueue('tenant1');
```

You may also create a queue for a particular connection as follows and push jobs to it:

```
$tenant1Connection = Queue::connection('connection_name');
$tenant1Connection->pushOn('queue_name', $job)
```

If you need to avoid the facade, you can do:

```
app('queue')->connection('connection_name')->pushOn('queue_name', $job);
```